# Catch error java response from endpoint in Mule

Tags: java, rest, exception, request, mule

I have an engine set up that validates an `xml` at a given endpoint.
`localhost/rules/my-rule`, if the `xml` file is consistent it returns the `xml` content. If not however, an exception is thrown:

> GeneralException: Combination missmatch

Which is an exception I declared. It's a normal Java Exception.
When I post a faulty file with a tool like postman I get this result:

```
Can't invoke perform method on "class %rule class%" with request data of 
"%data sent to endpoint%" 
(reason: ch.package.GeneralException: Combination missmatch). Combination missmatch
```

Which would be perfect. However upon sending it with mule I get:

> Route 0: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: HTTP POST on resource 'http://localhost/rules/my-rule/executions' failed: bad request (400).

Why can't I just get the error message? There isn't more insight when looking at the log:

> org.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.ErrorBuilder$ErrorImplementation
>   {   description=HTTP POST on resource
>   'http://localhost/rules/my-rule/executions'
>   failed: bad request (400).   detailedDescription=HTTP POST on resource
>   'http://localhost/rules/my-rule/executions'
>   failed: bad request (400).   errorType=HTTP:BAD_REQUEST
>   cause=org.mule.extension.http.api.request.validator.ResponseValidatorTypedException
>   errorMessage=
>   org.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.DefaultMessageBuilder$MessageImplementation
>   {
>   payload=org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamProvider@3239ebf7
>   mediaType=text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>   attributes=org.mule.extension.http.api.HttpResponseAttributes {
>   Status Code=400    Reason Phrase=    Headers=[
>         content-type=text/plain
>         transfer-encoding=chunked
>         date=Wed, 03 Jul 2019 07:16:19 GMT
>         connection=close    ] }   attributesMediaType=*/* }   childErrors=[] }] }

My flow configutation:

```
<scatter-gather doc:name="Distribute workload" doc:id="15151949-c61d-4629-9fd4-0a4e16d62eec" >
    <route >
        <!--Access to localhost/rules/my-rule>
        <flow-ref doc:name="CategoryToType" doc:id="e5d39afa-3b2a-45ef-81c0-afce77a76aef" name="validateCategoryToType" />
    </route>
</scatter-gather>
<error-handler>
    <on-error-propagate enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Propagate" doc:id="16001c58-7609-42a6-9bfa-1cd756998f27" >
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="8ec2af18-3e45-4d15-a373-5e9af74723d7" message='#[error]'/>
    </on-error-propagate>
</error-handler>
<sub-flow name="validateCategoryToType" doc:id="da38db3a-7d51-4fd1-bd06-9e58b872d468" >
    <foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="ff9944ba-5f87-4a5a-9392-a4b27c2f5fb0" collection="payload.Kunden" rootMessageVariableName="Kunden">
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="f33fa5ea-0b4d-4ac5-a247-90fd6978248d">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload>
                    <!--Some transformy stuff-->
                </ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" doc:id="53df928a-4fd1-4125-88e0-be73b006beee" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/rules/my-rule/execution>
            <http:headers><![CDATA[#[output application/java
                ---
                {
                "Content-Type" : "application/xml",
                "Accept" : "application/xml"
                }]]]></http:headers>
        </http:request>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="cc02312e-b71b-461c-bba0-077bfb1e9b7e" message="#[payload]" />
    </foreach>
</sub-flow>
```

Comment: Hi Pete, Have you defined global error handler? You are only getting generic error response

Comment: The error handler is only in scope of the flow. As far as I know each subflow will write on the error handler of the main flow, am I mistaken?

Comment: Which version of Mule you are using ?

Comment: I'm using the latest release 4.2

Comment: I would say define global handler and reference it, or use dataweave before logger , error.errordescription https://dzone.com/articles/error-handling-in-mule-1

Comment: Very nice and clean approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Global error handler, i have composed HTTP error request for you. You can expand it to other error types like API tool kit etc..

Also, extend further error messages by creating variables and capture postman payload into a variable

```
<on-error-propagate type="HTTP:BAD_REQUEST"
                  enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Propagate"
                  doc:id="73b29eaf-ebcd-4857-baea-4c2fb963b055">
                  <set-variable value="#[400]" doc:name="HTTP Status - 400"
                        doc:id="4017a80c-f968-4f09-8fbb-eaa4ce5d1413" variableName="httpStatus" />
                  <set-variable
                        value="Service is unable to handle request"
                        doc:name="errorMessage" doc:id="9ab2b50b-7aad-4460-b276-f5d50ffd1efe"
                        variableName="errorMessage" />
                  <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="df98f927-584c-454e-971e-79d2ff1e842d" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
error: {
    errorCode: error.errorType.identifier,
    errorDateTime: now() as String { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" },
    errorDescription:  error.description
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="6e6c0017-2b23-4bfa-83ef-2f77cc25aa08" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>

</on-error-propagate>
```

Comment: Is it possible to call a local error handler after a global one?

Comment: you can, but you wont need to call once you have defined global error handler. use error handling option on HTTP listener, `on error propogate` define error description in dataweave

Comment: I want to move an update upon failure, which is not necesseraly a global task

Comment: Move an update ? you can still use error handler option, this will be automatically picked up form global error handler